# Missing cli.json file when creating a new Vue project using Amplify

Tags: vue.js, aws-amplify

Missing cli.json file when creating a new Vue project using Amplify. I am following the [official tutorial](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/installation/q/integration/vue/)

I get as far as **Initialize a new backend** and run *amplify init*:

[image]

Initializing finishes with the following (it does not matter whether I answer yes or no to the share information on failure message):

[image]

And here's the file structure:

[image]

I also notice that the aws-exports.js file was not created. Oddly enough, the aws-exports.js file is listed in the **.gitignore** file.

I have tried a few times to create a new project, in VS and in the windows console. I have also tried creating the Vue app using Vue 2 and 3 and come up against the same issue.

In my final attempt, I came across the same issue but proceeded to "successfully" add the graphQl API but this error was displayed when I ran *amplify push* to update the backend:

> An error occurred during the push operation: /
> The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records

I presume this is because the aws-exports.js file that contains the access key does not exist?

I'd appreciate any help in sorting this out.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

solved!

I mistakenly created the project within another project.